# Restore Previous Versions dialog unable to open drop-down menu under "Open" and "Restore"

Tags: windows, network-share, windows-server-2019, shadow-copies

We have a Windows Server 2019 box that is hosting some file shares. We also have Previous Versions enabled with a default (for now) schedule for self-service file restore.

When people open the Previous Versions tab, there are two buttons underneath the version list - Open and Restore, both with drop-down arrows. However, nothing happens when they click the arrow. This is somewhat inconvenient because there is a "Restore to..." option under the Restore button. Googling doesn't find any useful links/guides (or my google-fu is failing me).

I know that they can click "Open" to have the version opened in a new window, and then copy/paste or drag/drop the file to be recovered to a different location, but it's less convenient and we would like to avoid this.

Has anyone seen this or knows where to look to fix the issue?